# Read "active" mail message on Outlook context-menu action?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

Hi i am trying to **read email content on click of a custom button** in outlook .
i.e : right click on a mail and on selected mail click custom Button **GoToApp** 
and it should read all content of mail including text,attachment info and plain text and image 
i have attached snapshot of outlook page.

i tried

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders‌​.olFolderInbox);
if (myInbox.Items.Count > 0) {
    // Grab the Subject
    lblSubject.Text = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[1]).Subject;
}
```

Bit it is not working it is cosidering mail is not there in default folder location.

how i can achieve that please help.
[image]

thanks 
nikhil

Comment: i tried 
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
if (myInbox.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                // Grab the Subject
                lblSubject.Text = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[1]).Subject;
}

Comment: it is not working it is cosidering mail is not there in default folder location.

Answer (score 1):

In the [ItemContextMenuDisplay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175110%28v=office.12%29.aspx) event (that is fired on the right-click) there is an [Outlook.Selection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219970%28v=office.12%29.aspx) object passed in as the second parameter.

Use this selection to determine the currently selected/active items, if any. The objects will need to be cast to `MailItem` as appropriate. (Remember, indexes in the Outlook Object Model *start at 1*, not 0.)

It is not possible to determine the exact item the right-click was performed upon (there might be multiple items selected or there might be *no* items selected), but the item that the right-click was performed upon *will* be one of the selected items. Also, the item currently in the reading-pane might *not* correspond to the selected item(s).

Happy coding.

Comment: thanks for reply  but i am able to figure out how to implement can u have some code snippet for the same ..which will make it some clear ..

Comment: Read the documentation and try a few things. Then, if there is a *specific* question about a *specific* issue, post a question focusing on just that.

Comment: Hi i am using "currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();" then i am able to get all the details of mail but on my custom button click i am not able to work it out .

Comment: currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(CurrentExplorer_Event); is used to call CurrentExplorer_Event function .. it is working but how to make it work for on click of my custom button ?

Comment: how to use this event ApplicationEvents_11_ItemContextMenuDisplayEventHandler ItemContextMenuDisplay

Comment: expression.ItemContextMenuDisplay(CommandBar, Selection)  is for displaying the context menu and selection is where to display ..

Comment: Yes, that is what the event is for. Remember the selection (MailItem) *in* that event, and then use the information when when the custom action has been clicked. (I recommend just saving the Message ID and using that to re-open the item.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the Ribbon callback for a custom ribbon button in the MailItem context menu.

```
public void BtnClickHandler(Office.IRibbonControl btn)
    {
        var ex = btn?.Context?.Parent as Outlook.Explorer;

        if (ex == null) return;

        foreach (var sel in ex.Selection)
        {
            var mailItem = sel as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (mailItem != null) DoSomethingWith(mailItem);
        }
    }
```